# Is there any best practice that describes whether host multiple azure app service on the same service plan or separate them?

Tags: azure-app-service-plans

We have 7 app services (microservice architecture) and we are wondering what could be the best approach of hosting them, is it to host them on the same azure service 
plan or separate them ? Is there any best practice or guidance ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest factor in deciding on hosting multiple app services (slots) on one service plan vs one app service per service plan is going to be resource allocation.

**All** of the app services in a service plan share the resources of that plan.  This lack of separation could result in performance issues if you are not careful.

As a rule of thumb, you should have one app service running per service plan for production applications.  The only time you would want to have another app service slot running is for hot-swapping slots for a production deployment.

For non-production applications, you may have more flexibility, as long as you are not affecting your user's productivity.

**Side Note:** Have you researched Azure Functions?  That may be a viable alternative for the architecture you are describing.